# $X=Z(xy-1)\subset \mathbb{A}_k^2$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1_k$

Tags: commutative-algebra, zariski-topology, morphism

I need to prove that $X=Z(xy-1)\subset \mathbb{A}_k^2$ is **not** isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1_k$.

I solved an exercise where I proved that, for instance, some $X\subset \mathbb{A}_k^3$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^2_k$, by constructing a morphism and showing that it is bijection (is the idea correct?).

However, I am stucked to show that is not isomorphic.

Well, I thought that $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ being a field and $X$ not (because $(0,0)\not\in X$), so they are not isomorphic.

However, this is as I've done with homomorphisms (rings, etc.), not morphisms between algebraic sets. I do not know if I can consider such thing as be or not a field.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to show the coordinate rings are non-isomorphic as $k$-algebras.
The coordinate ring of $\Bbb A_k^1$ is just $k[t]$. That of $X$ is
$$\frac{k[x,y]}{(xy-1)}\cong k[x,x^{-1}].$$
You need to show this ring isn't a polynomial ring. What say are the units
of $k[x,x^{-1}]$?

Comment: So, $X\cong Y\iff k[X]\cong k[Y]$? This last is an homomorphism of rings, right? Well, I think so that for one side $k[t]$ is a polinomyal ring with just 'some' units, but in $k[x,x^{-1}]$ I have all elements units (except $0$), so they are not isomorphic...? Thanks very much.